# Connection time out in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multer-gridfs-storage

I'm trying to upload a media file and few strings but I'm getting connection time out.

I want to upload media files like image , video with details of the file to MongoDB.

While the media file is uploaded the details which I enter do not .(description and name of the media file)

***the error I'm getting is***
[enter image description here][1]
`` MongooseError: Operation `mediainfos.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms at Timeout.<anonymous> ``

***the code I'm using is***

```
const conn =  mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
},(err,database)=>{
  db = database
})


let gfs;
conn.once("open", () => {
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection("uploads");
});
 
const  storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: "uploads",
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  },
  
});
const upload =  multer({storage});

//Upload Files to DB

app.post('/upload',upload.single('file'),async (req,res)=>{
const fileName = req.file != null ? req.file.filename :null
console.log("Media Name "+req.body.medianame)

  const MediaInfo = new mediaInfo({
    media_id:fileName,
    media_name:req.body.medianame,
    media_description:req.body.mediadescription
  })
try{
  const NewMediaInfo = await MediaInfo.save()
  res.send("Works Fine")
  
}catch(error){
console.log(error)
}
  
   res.redirect('/');
});
```

MediaInfo is the schema

```
const Mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = Mongoose.Schema


let mediaInfo = new Schema({
    media_id:{
        type: String
    },
    media_name:{
        type:String
    },
    media_description:{
        type:String
    },

});

module.exports = Mongoose.model('mediaInfos',mediaInfo)
```

*ERROR IMAGE*
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqMdC.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error Message from MongoDB "Operation \`disneys.insertOne()\` buffering timed out after 10000ms""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65193572/error-message-from-mongodb-operation-disneys-insertone-buffering-timed-out)

Comment: I tried to make it an async function but I'm not able to get the `conn` value . and rest of the suggestions are not working