# MongooseError: Operation `urls.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to make a post request that saves find data in MongoDB or create one if it does not exist then I got the error like this

```
MongooseError: Operation `urls.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
```

my main.js

```
    require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Basic Configuration
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(cors());

app.use("/public", express.static(`${process.cwd()}/public`));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(process.cwd() + "/views/index.html");
});

// Your first API endpoint
app.get("/api/hello", function (req, res) {
  res.json({ greeting: "hello API" });
});

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});

mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGODB_CONNECT,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  },
  () => {
    console.log("Connected to mongoDB");
  }
);

let urlSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  original: { type: String, required: true },
  short: Number,
});

let Url = mongoose.model("Url", urlSchema);
let responseObject = {};

app.post(
  "/api/shorturl/new",
  bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }),
  (request, response) => {
    let inputUrl = request.body["url"];

    responseObject["original_url"] = inputUrl;

    let inputShort = 1;

    Url.findOne({})
      .sort({ short: "desc" })
      .exec((error, result) => {

       // THE ERROR APPEARS

        console.log(error);

        if (!error && result != undefined) {
          inputShort = result.short + 1;
        }
        if (!error) {
          Url.findOneAndUpdate(
            { original: inputUrl },
            { original: inputUrl, short: inputShort },
            { new: true, upsert: true },
            (error, savedUrl) => {
              if (!error) {
                responseObject["short_url"] = savedUrl.short;
                response.json(responseObject);
              }
            }
          );
        }
      });
  }
);
```

my dependencies

```
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"dotenv": "^8.2.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"mongoose": "^5.11.10"
```

I already try some solutions in similar question like:

- delete node_module file and reinstalled mongoose
- change the version of nodejs in MongoDB cluster to
  2.2.12 or later
- change my IP to google public DNS 8888 8844

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090440/how-to-solve-mongoose-v5-11-0-model-find-error-operation-products-find-bu?

Comment: I did try that, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I did try to set up a new environment and using the same MongoDB database, it turns out my database get problem may be the connection,
I tried to create a new project and setup access from everywhere and chose the server near to my place, it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65902705/11322237) the problem is very likely to be that **YOU DO NOT HAVE** your localhost database running.

#### How to fix

Start both `mongod` and `mongo` processes.