# I am getting the error MongooseError: Operation `products.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms AND error: [MongoNetworkError]

Tags: mongodb, server

here is my code.

I get the Catch an error:  MongooseError: Operation `products.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
at Timeout. (C:\Users\tanis\Desktop\amazon-clone\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:20)

The server is still running tho... "Server started at http://localhost:5000"

I tried the try catch block, I also tried exporting it using module.export but does not work. Please help me solve this error. I tried a lot but it does not solve... My Product.find() is in productRoute.js file and the Product is exported from the productModule.js file. Please help.

```
     Server.js file
    dotenv.config();
        
        const mongodbUrl = config.MONGODB_URL;
        
        mongoose.connect(mongodbUrl,
         {
        
          useNewUrlParser: true,
        
          useUnifiedTopology: true,
        
          useCreateIndex: true
        
        }).catch(error => console.log(error.reason));
        
        
        
        const app = express();
        
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        
        app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
        
        app.use("/api/products", productRoute);
    
    
         **- productRoute.js file**
import express from 'express';
import Product from '../models/productModel';
import { isAuth, isAdmin } from '../util';
        const router = express.Router();
        
        router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
          try{
          const products = await Product.find({});
          res.send(products);
          }
          catch(e) {
            console.log('Catch an error: ', e)
          } 
        });
        
        router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
          const product = await Product.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
          if (product) {
            res.send(product);
          } else {
            res.status(404).send({ message: "Product Not Found." });
          }
        });
        
        router.put("/:id", isAuth, isAdmin, async (req, res) => {
          const productId = req.params.id;
          const product = await Product.findById(productId);
          if (product) {
            product.name = req.body.name;
            product.price = req.body.price;
            product.image = req.body.image;
            product.brand = req.body.brand;
            product.category = req.body.category;
            product.countInStock = req.body.countInStock;
            product.description = req.body.description;
            const updatedProduct = await product.save();
            if (updatedProduct) {
              return res.status(200).send({ message: 'Product Updated', data: updatedProduct });
            }
          }
          return res.status(500).send({ message: ' Error in Updating Product.' });
        
        });
        
        router.delete("/:id", isAuth, isAdmin, async (req, res) => {
          const deletedProduct = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
          if (deletedProduct) {
            await deletedProduct.remove();
            res.send({ message: "Product Deleted" });
          } else {
            res.send("Error in Deletion.");
          }
        });
        
        
        router.post("/", isAuth, isAdmin, async (req, res) => {
          const product = new Product({
            name: req.body.name,
            price: req.body.price,
            image: req.body.image,
            brand: req.body.brand,
            category: req.body.category,
            countInStock: req.body.countInStock,
            description: req.body.description,
            rating: req.body.rating,
            numReviews: req.body.numReviews,
          });
          const newProduct = await product.save();
          if (newProduct) {
            return res.status(201).send({ message: 'New Product Created', data: newProduct });
          }
          return res.status(500).send({ message: ' Error in Creating Product.' });
        })
        
        
        export default router;
    
         - **productModel.js file**
        
            import mongoose from 'mongoose';
            
            const prodctSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
              name: { type: String, required: true },
              image: { type: String, required: true },
              brand: { type: String, required: true },
              price: { type: Number, default: 0, required: true },
              category: { type: String, required: true },
              countInStock: { type: Number, default: 0, required: true },
              description: { type: String, required: true },
              rating: { type: Number, default: 0, required: true },
              numReviews: { type: Number, default: 0, required: true },
            });
            
            const productModel = mongoose.model("Product", prodctSchema);
            //module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", prodctSchema);
            export default productModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar Post #[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090440/how-to-solve-mongoose-v5-11-0-model-find-error-operation-products-find-bu)

The Reason you are getting this error as per the MongoDB documentation is
**Your model is being called before the connection is established. You need to use async/await with connect() or createConnection()**

I Think what should work in your case is adding a .then block
here is the solution

```
  mongoose.connect(mongodbUrl, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
}).then(
    const app = express(); 
    app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
    app.use("/api/users", userRoute); 
    app.use("/api/products", productRoute);
    ).catch(error => console.log(error.reason));
```

More Elegant approch would be to seprate the app and server logic

create a app.js file and add

```
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/products", productRoute);
module.exports = app;
```

and in server.js import that app.js after sorting the db connection

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });
const app = require('./app');

mongoose.connect(mongodbUrl,
         {
          useNewUrlParser: true,
          useUnifiedTopology: true,
          useCreateIndex: true
        }).then(()=>{
console.log('DB connection successful!')
}).catch(error => console.log(error.reason));

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port http://localhost:${port}... `);
});
```

This way your app will start listening to the request only after the Mongodb is connected

any of these 2 option will work as the solution for your issues

Comment: thank you! It is imported sorry my bad I did not include it in the post.. but now I did..

Comment: I have updated my Answer based on your comment.. if this solution works please mark that as a answer and do upvote it

Answer (score -1):

I am running in to the same error and my connection used to work fine before. In my case I am not even getting the success(try) or failure(catch) console log. With no error Mongoose seems like entirely ignoring the connect() call. In order to see if it does execute the connect(), I tried to fudge the URI by making it invalid and did get an error. This proves that the connect() does attempt to connect but just fails to actually connect and doesn't return any error. After the connect (from Express API server) when I try to make the API call from my front-end I get this infamous `Error fetching products Operation` products.find() `buffering timed out after 10000ms` error which indicates there was no DB connection established. Any idea? I am on Mongoose 5.11.16 and even tried to downgrade it to 5.10.x. My node version is 12.18.0