# MongooseError: Operation users.insertOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms” in Mongo Db atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js, mongodb-atlas

I am currently working with node and mongoDB
here is my code

```html
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

dotenv.config();

mongoose
  .connect(
    `mongodb+srv://OmniBotBuilder:${process.env.DBPASS}${process.env.DBUSER}.kx2vg.mongodb.net/${process.env.DBNAME}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
    {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    }
  )
  .catch(() => console.error("Unable to connect to DB"));

mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {});

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const omniGamesSchema = new Schema({
  discordId: Number,
  steamId: Number,
});

const omniGamesModel = mongoose.model("omniGamesSchema", omniGamesSchema);

const createNewUser = (discordId, steamId) => {
  const newUserMap = new omniGamesModel({
    discordId: discordId,
    steamId: steamId,
  });

  newUserMap.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  });
};

export { createNewUser };
```

and the error i am getting is this one [image]

MongooseError: Operation `omnigamesschemas.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
at Timeout. (C:\Users\dahiy\OneDrive\Desktop\bots\omni-games\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:198:23)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve Mongoose v5.11.0 model.find() error: Operation \`products.find()\` buffering timed out after 10000ms"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090440/how-to-solve-mongoose-v5-11-0-model-find-error-operation-products-find-bu)

Comment: Please do not use a stack snippet for code that isn't runnable. Stack snippets are only meant for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code that can be run on a browser. Please format your code using a [code block](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/8289918) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This issue normally is caused because:**

- wrong auth, by the meaning the mongo path string is wrong so maybe double check your pass and username
- check the allowed IP to access the database from the mongo website, if you want it to be accessed from everywhere just use IP: `0.0.0.0/0`
- Your internet connection might be slow to the point it cannot connect to the DB

Hope you found this helpful! :)

Comment: your third point worked for me as it started to work when i connected my pc with mobile hotspot

Comment: happy it helped!

Comment: it helped but my net is much faster than my mobile hotspot its kind of weird that it works fine on mobile hotspot but not on Wi-Fi

Answer (score 0):

1. You can open https://cloud.mongodb.com/
2. Click connect Goto the Connect your application
3. Select Driver Node.js version 4.1 leter
4. Copy the link which you have to show than paste this link to your
   project .env file now try to run application connect Database and
   check.