# Mongoose gives error on insertOne() on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
`C:\code\WebApp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:158
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^
MongooseError: Operation `posts.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\code\WebApp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:158:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
```

Here's my app.js.

```
const express = require('express');
const app=express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('dotenv/config');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const postRoutes = require('./routes/posts');

app.use('/posts',postRoutes);

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('we are at home');
});

mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

mongoose.connect(
    process.env.DB_CONNECT,
    { newURLParser : true,
    useUnifiedTopology : true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    },
    () =>
    console.log('Connected to DB')
);
app.listen(3000);
```

Here I have already tried to reset my whitelisted IP on MongoAtlas & using try-catch block also didn't help. Can someone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: you didn't share anything about the insertion operation. Where are you inserting?

Comment: See if these help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68777855/2282634 https://stackoverflow.com/q/65090440/2282634