# MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am getting an error when trying to insert a document in the collection

```
MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
```

My dbLogic.js looks like this

```
const mongoose = require ("mongoose");
const User = require("./Collections/User")

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017")        
//console.log("Connected to db: ");    
           
addUser()        
async function addUser() {        
    const user = await  User.create({ name: "Phiri", age: 40 })    

    console.log(user);
}
```

I also tried doing `mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/myDatabase");`

The connectionstring I am using `mongodb://localhost:27017` is obtained from MongoDB compass. I am able to connect to the database using `mongosh`, and I can insert records etc.

My User.js looks like this

```
const mongoose = require ("mongoose");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    age : Number
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

The full errormessage I get

```
PS C:\Users\my_is\Programming\Project> node dbLogic.js
Listening on Port: 2000
(node:14400) [MONGOOSE] DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: the `strictQuery` option will be switched back to `false` by default in Mongoose 7. Use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);` if you want to prepare for this change. Or use `mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);` to suppress this warning.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\my_is\Programming\Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:175
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\my_is\Programming\Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:175:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
```

I found this thread (among others), that didn't help me:
[MongooseError: Operation users.insertOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms” in Mongo Db atlas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68759205/mongooseerror-operation-users-insertone-buffering-timed-out-after-10000ms-in)

Ps. I am running locally.

Comment: Have you tried `mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")`? Also, try specifying your database like so: `mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/databaseName")`

Comment: @bosowski Wow, I can't believe that was it. I spent more than a day on this issue. Thanks mate. Pls make it so that I can accept your answer as the solution

Comment: It seems that bothe ways work. If I don't specify a database name, it seems that it inserts in the default database, which is "test"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017")` instead of the `mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017")`.

> If connecting fails on your machine, try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html