# Error : Operation users.insertMany() buffering timed out after 10000ms when using mongoose in the following code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am having a hard time finding an error in this following code i wanted to connect to  a database and add some data to it but iam getting an error whose info is specified below

**This is the code of `Server.js`which is the server of the application **

```
import userdata from './userdata.js';
import data from "./data.js"
import mongoose  from 'mongoose';
import userrouter from './routers/userrouter.js';


const app=express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/purpleshades',{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true,
    useCreateIndex:true
})

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use('/api/users',userrouter)
app.use((err,req,res,next)=>{
    res.status(500).send({message:err.message})
})
const port=process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log(`serve at http://localhost:${port}`);
})
```

This is the code of the `userserver.js` which is the router file of the user router which handles the user many request

```
import userdata from "../userdata.js";
import User from "../models/usermodel.js";
import expressAsyncHandler from "express-async-handler";

const userrouter=express.Router()

userrouter.get('/seed',expressAsyncHandler( async(req,res)=>{
    const createdusers=await User.insertMany(userdata.users)
    res.send({createdusers})
}))

export default userrouter
```

The data file is asfollows which is called userdata.js

```
const userdata={
    users:[
        {
            name:'Prashanth',
            email:'prashanthyarram@gmail.com',
            password:bcrypt.hashSync('1234',8),
            isadmin:true
        },
        {
            name:'ramesh',
            email:'ramesh@gmail.com',
            password:bcrypt.hashSync('5678',8),
            isadmin:true
        },
        {
            name:'jhon',
            email:'jnonny@gmail.com',
            password:bcrypt.hashSync('91011',8),
            isadmin:true
        },
        {
            name:'cristine',
            email:'cristene@gmail.com',
            password:bcrypt.hashSync('1213',8),
            isadmin:true
        }

    ]
}
export default userdata
```

Now the error is as follows
`` "message": "Operation `users.insertMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms" ``

How do I  get rid of this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve Mongoose v5.11.0 model.find() error: Operation \`products.find()\` buffering timed out after 10000ms"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090440/how-to-solve-mongoose-v5-11-0-model-find-error-operation-products-find-bu)

Comment: make sure that you are connected to MongoDB before the execution of any query.

Comment: share the usermodel.js as well. As far I can see, you have not used the connected mongoose  instance to execute the create query, but instead used a different mongoose instance.

Comment: I have finally found the answer to my question and it is that ```useCreateIndex:true``` is actually deprecated so just removing it from the code actually solved the problem