# Why am I getting this error in Mongoose MongDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am getting this error
[image]

My code:

```
// MODULES
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


// CONNECTING TO THE DATABASE
const url = "mongodb://localhose:27017/fruitsDB";
mongoose.connect(url, {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true});


// CREATE
// schema
const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  rating: Number,
  review: String
});

// model
const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

// collection
const fruit = new Fruit({
  name: "Apple",
  rating: 7,
  review: "Pretty nice."
})

fruit.save();
```

I am getting error after running the code. Please guide me on how to solve this error.
Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: apparently, your MongoDB server is not running

Comment: Because your DB is not connected. place mongoose.connect(url, {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true}); in try catch and on connection console.log DB Connection message for your own confirmation and in catch console log your error if you are facing and figure it out

Comment: maybe some of this helps ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090440/how-to-solve-mongoose-v5-11-0-model-find-error-operation-products-find-bu

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551