# Querying a mongo DB causes Heroku timeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I'm using a simple node app with an express server and attempting to deploy it to heroku and a single query to the database causes my app to crash with an H13 error after about 10 seconds. The error says it closed without response.

crash logs:

```
2022-06-20T04:01:55.992187+00:00 app[web.1]: const err = new MongooseError(message);      
2022-06-20T04:01:55.992188+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-06-20T04:01:55.992189+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-06-20T04:01:55.992190+00:00 app[web.1]: MongooseError: Operation `classifications.findOne()` bufdOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
2022-06-20T04:01:55.992191+00:00 app[web.1]: at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/dgoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:151:23)
2022-06-20T04:01:55.992191+00:00 app[web.1]: at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17))                                                                                         2022-06-20T
2022-06-20T04:01:55.992192+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)2022-06-20T04:01:55.992196+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-06-20T04:01:55.992197+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js v17.7.2                               without re
2022-06-20T04:01:56.002582+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed728b0fb8-d2 without response" method=GET path="/al/classes/class-1a" host=wcsn-backend.herokuapp.com s=503 bytes
request_id=728b0fb8-d2bf-44f4-ae5c-793401a76653 fwd="216.198.98.78" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10015ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-06-20T04:01:56.161890+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-06-20T04:01:56.253251+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

The entire code can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO9RS.png).

or here with omitted commented out code:

```
server.get('/:state/:classification/:className', async (req, res) => {
  let className = req.params.className.replaceAll('-', ' ');
  className = className.replaceAll('/', ' ');
  const { url } = await classificationsModel.findOne(
    {
      name: className.toLowerCase(),
      associatedState: req.params.state.toUpperCase(),
    },
    { url: 1, _id: 0 }
  );
  console.log(url);
  res.json('hello world');
  teamList = [];
});
```

Again locally [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9yRY.png) is produced in the console and 'hello world' is returned as json. Why is it different on heroku and how can I fix it?

Comment: How are you connecting to the database?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090440/how-to-solve-mongoose-v5-11-0-model-find-error-operation-products-find-bu

Comment: mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, () => console.log('This application has been connected to the Mongo DB!')) The first 2 endpoints work fine on Heroku, it's not until it attempts to pull information down does it run into a problem.

Comment: what is in your database? how many items etc