# Error: MongooseError: Operation `tours.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms at Timeout.<anonymous>

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm running MongoDB Atlas on node express and I got this error.
Also I have set my network access from anywhere.
Every time I use testTours.save() method it somehow invokes the tours.insertOne() method and creates a collection by itself.
What to do?

Here is my code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const app = require('./app');

dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });

const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace(
  '<PASSWORD>',
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
);

async function start() {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(DB, () => console.log('DB connection successful'));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

start();
testTour
  .save()
  .then(doc => {
    console.log(doc);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error: ', err);
  });
const port = 3000 || process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`);
});
```

Comment: Maybe show where you use `tours.insertOne`

Comment: I earlier created a tours collection in Atlas but I have deleted it. But still its showing the same error

Comment: Every time I run start my server a "tours" collection is created on its own and that is causing the error. Please help me out here.

Comment: Seems like you are still using it somewhere

Comment: It keeps getting created because of using models. The tours.insertOne() is called when we save the docement but this error only creates the collection, no data is saved in the database. Every time I try to save it and see in Atlas only the collection is made without the data.

Comment: I guess that you've made a mistake in the code that inserts the data

Comment: It's just one function call testTour.save() what could have gone wrong in that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090440/how-to-solve-mongoose-v5-11-0-model-find-error-operation-products-find-bu

Comment: You are calling `save` before the connection is established. You never wait for `start` to finish

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for connection to be established

```
start().then(() => {
testTour
  .save()
  .then(doc => {
    console.log(doc);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error: ', err);
  });
})
```