# Can't save user to Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, save

Getting this warning right after I write out the user.save()

```
C:\Users\lenaf\MongooseProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:153
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lenaf\MongooseProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:153:23)        
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

Script.js file

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("./User");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/SUCCESS")

const user = new User({ name: "Bill", age: 35});
user.save().then(() => console.log("User Saved"));
```

User.js page is

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number 
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Mongoose is driving me nuts- it's truly never worked for me- so if someone knows a simple straight answer to this, I would much appreciate it.
And I have found the other answers to this posted before- go to atlas and make sure it has your correct IP address. Needless to say, that didn't work, and I have also made sure that my MongoDB is running via the task manager. Please please please help!

Comment: Make sure MongoDB is really running on your computer and uses port 27017.

Comment: Does localhost resolve on your Windows machine? Try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. See also other potential fixes at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090440/how-to-solve-mongoose-v5-11-0-model-find-error-operation-products-find-bu