# I'm getting an error in Mongoose when instantiating an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a database, and add data to a collection using Mongoose, but I keep getting an error.

My code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", { useNewUrlParser: true }); 

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);  

module.exports = Fruit;

const fruit = new Fruit({
    name: "Apple",
    rating: 7,
    review: "Pretty solid as a fruit."
});

fruit.save().then(() => console.log("User Saved"));
```

And the error I get:

```
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `fruits.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kinga\OneDrive\Desktop\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:186:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:568:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:511:7)

Node.js v19.6.0
```

The statement const err = new MongooseError(message); directs me to a file, in the node modules, called collection.js

Comment: It seems you're not using the mongoose API properly, the connection method is `asynchronous`. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/65650870/8843585

Answer (score 0):

The `connect()` method is asynchronous, and needs to be awaited before used

```
await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Since you are using commonJS, you cannot `await` anything outside an async function. Something like this would work

```
async function connect() {
  await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", {useNewUrlParser: true });
  return mongoose
}
```

But now you need to use `.then()` and `.catch()` methods to use the `connect()` function properly and not get the same error again

More info on async functions:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Follow the official documentation for mongoose, as it explains better how things work and is up-to-date
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html